# Pinot Kubernetes authentication/ACL

Tags: kubernetes, apache-pinot, pinot

I'm new to Pinot and K8s, I have setup Pinot in K8s environment using helm, and trying to add authentication properties using this instruction(https://docs.pinot.apache.org/operators/tutorials/authentication/basic-auth-access-control).

How to add these properties to those config files and make it work? (e.g. */var/pinot/controller/config/pinot-controller.conf) Config files are read-only, and I don't think we can use commands like in K8s envrionment?

```
bin/pinot-admin.sh StartController -configFileName /path/to/controller.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario you may try updating the ConfigMap by running

‘*kubectl get configmap <CONFIGMAP_NAME> -o yaml > configmap.yaml*’ After that, edit the config.yaml and look for pinot-controller.conf. Here you may edit the parameters as required. Then apply the changes by running ‘*kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml*’. Once done, restart the pods for it to take effect. Attached are some documentations for a good read.[1][2]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

[2] https://docs.pinot.apache.org/operators/tutorials/authentication/basic-auth-access-control